# Use HTTP between backend k8s services and AWS LoadBalancer Controller, and HTTPS between client and AWS LoadBalancer Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

I want to use HTTP between backend k8s services and AWS LoadBalancer Controller, and HTTPS between client and AWS LoadBalancer Controller.

With my current below setup (ingress.yaml, main.tf, service.yaml) on every communication level I use HTTPS. The Argo CD website under argo.goldendevops.com works fine with HTTPS, but the website goldendevops.com that uses Nginx deployment and service doesn't work because with this setup I don't have setup certificates for Nginx and I get below error in Nginx pod (just my container is not prepared to get HTTPS):

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.1
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.184
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 65536:1048576
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
2023/07/13 17:21:29 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
10.0.102.221 - - [13/Jul/2023:17:22:15 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x90\x01\x00\x00\x8C\x03\x03\xF3l\xD0\xB5\xCF\x08F\xB6n\xE0Dq\x92o\xE5\x84\xE7_sT\xFD\xB986B\xDE\xAA\xA4\xCE\x1F\xE5\xDC\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
10.0.102.221 - - [13/Jul/2023:17:22:23 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x90\x01\x00\x00\x8C\x03\x03\x9DB\xBF\xBF\xAAD0\xB4\xF8\x1C\xA3s\x06\xC8\xEC!\xC2K\xC0\xF6[\x12\xA2\x03q\xE7\xDCR\x93\xB6M\xE3\x00\x00&\xC0+\xC0/\xC0#\xC0'\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\xC0,\xC00\xC0$\xC0(\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```

Currently I use HTTPS also in internal communication, what I want to change to HTTP only. When I try to change the internal communication to HTTP by myself by below 3 steps then the Argo CD website starts getting error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" and in Nginx container I get error "http: TLS Handshake error":

*Change "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS" to "HTTP"

*Change services ports in ingress.yaml and servie.yaml to 80

*Delete "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: HTTP2" (because it supports only HTTPS)

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    # Use this annotation (which must match a service name) to route traffic to HTTP2 backends.
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.argogrpc: |
      [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "Content-Type", "values":["application/grpc"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.golden-devops-helm-release: |
      [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "Content-Type", "values":["application/grpc"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:11111111111
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
  name: argocd
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argo.goldendevops.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: argogrpc
            port:
              number: 443
            namespace: argocd
        pathType: Prefix
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              number: 443
            namespace: argocd
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: goldendevops.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: golden-devops-helm-release
            port:
              number: 443
            namespace: argocd
        pathType: Prefix
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: golden-devops-helm-release
            port:
              number: 443
            namespace: argocd
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - argo.goldendevops.com
    - goldendevops.com
```

Service for Argo CD (for Nginx is very similar):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: HTTP2 #This tells AWS to send traffic from the ALB using HTTP2. Can use GRPC as well if you want to leverage GRPC specific features
  labels:
    app: argogrpc
  name: argogrpc
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "443"
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

main.tf:

```
locals {
  account_id = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
  tags = {
    Name      = "${var.cluster_name}"
    Project   = "eks-demo"
    ManagedBy = "terraform"
  }
}

module "eks" {
  source                          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version                         = "18.29.1"
  cluster_name                    = var.cluster_name
  cluster_version                 = var.cluster_version
  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true
  enable_irsa                     = true

  cluster_addons = {
    coredns = {
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
    kube-proxy = {}
    vpc-cni = {
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
  }

  vpc_id     = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.public_subnets

  manage_aws_auth_configmap = true

  aws_auth_users = [
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:user/jakubszuber-admin"
      username = "cluster-admin"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
  ]

  # Extend cluster security group rules
  cluster_security_group_additional_rules = {
    egress_nodes_ephemeral_ports_tcp = {
      description                = "To node 1025-65535"
      protocol                   = "tcp"
      from_port                  = 1025
      to_port                    = 65535
      type                       = "egress"
      source_node_security_group = true
    }
  }

  node_security_group_additional_rules = {
    ingress_allow_access_from_control_plane = {
      type                          = "ingress"
      protocol                      = "tcp"
      from_port                     = 9443
      to_port                       = 9443
      source_cluster_security_group = true
      description                   = "Allow access from control plane to webhook port of AWS load balancer controller"
    }
    ingress_self_all = {
      description = "Node to node all ports/protocols"
      protocol    = "-1"
      from_port   = 0
      to_port     = 0
      type        = "ingress"
      self        = true
    }
    ingress_all = {
      description      = "Node all ingress"
      protocol         = "-1"
      from_port        = 0
      to_port          = 0
      type             = "ingress"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    }
    egress_all = {
      description      = "Node all egress"
      protocol         = "-1"
      from_port        = 0
      to_port          = 0
      type             = "egress"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    }
  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    bottlerocket_nodes = {
      ami_type      = "BOTTLEROCKET_x86_64"
      platform      = "bottlerocket"
      min_size      = 1
      max_size      = 2
      desired_size  = 1      # TODO change those 3 numbers
      capacity_type = "SPOT"

      # this will get added to what AWS provides
      bootstrap_extra_args = <<-EOT
      # extra args added
      [settings.kernel]
      lockdown = "integrity"
      EOT
    }
  }
}
```

I would be so thankful for help I am working with that problem for many hours but because of my experience (I am 17) it's so problematic for my. I really would appreciate any help from your guys!

Btw. here is an article that I was using for my project: https://fewmorewords.com/eks-with-argocd-using-terraform and https://github.com/jayanath/k8-eks-argocd-terraform/

When I try to change the internal communication to HTTP by myself by below 3 steps then the Argo CD website starts getting error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" and in Nginx container I get error "http: TLS Handshake error":

*Change "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS" to "HTTP"

*Change services ports in ingress.yaml and servie.yaml to 80

*Delete "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: HTTP2" (because it supports only HTTPS)